# Converting Knowledge base to prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

New Task:

I have a set of objects aka fruits in my bag:

```
apple(b).
orange(c).
pear(d).
carrot(e).
onion(f).
pepper(g).
```

And these are the rules:

1. ∀x, Fruit(x) V Vegetable(x) [everything is a fruit or vegetable]
2. ∀x, Apple(x) -> Red(x) V Green(x) [Apples are red or green]
3. ∀x, Apple(x) V Orange(x) V Pear(x)) -> Fruit(x) [apples, oranges and pears are fruits]
4. ∀x, Carrot(x) V Pepper(x) -> Vegetable(x) [carrots and peppers are veges]
5. ∀x, fruit(x) -> tasty(x)   [all fruit are tasty]
6. ∀x, Carrot(x) -> tasty(x)   [all carrot are tasty]
7. ∀x, Onion(x) -> ¬tasty(x) [onion are not tasty]

Old Task *completed*:

1. ∀x, Dogs(x) V Cats(x) [everything is a dog or a cat]
2. ∀x, GShephard(x) -> Black(x) V White(x) [germanshephard are black or white]
3. ∀x, GShephard(x) V Canine(x) V Rottweiler(x)) -> Dog(x) [germanshephard, canine and rottweiler are dog]
4. ∀x, lion(x) -> hairy(x) [all lion are hairy]
5. ∀x, fish(x) -> ¬hairy(x) [fish are not hairy]

Based on what Daniel helped me learn and what I've tried on my own this is the code i've come up with:

```
% the Facts

apple(a).
apple(b).
orange(c).
pear(d).
carrot(e).
onion(f).
pepper(g)
```

I want to be able to ask these questions to my knowledge base:

1. What fruits are red?
2. Is some onion tasty?
3. What things are coloured?
4. Is there a tasty vegetable?

So far, only 2 and 3 works when I use the queries: 2 `tasty(f)` returns false which i think is correct and for 3 I use `coloured(X)` and it returns the apples. Any idea how to get ask queries to get answers for 1 and 4?

Comment: "Please do my homework" is really not OK.

Comment: This is not homework. I'm trying to understand prolog and is trying to encode a KB from my study guide. I haven't seen these particular statements be converted to prolog in any other textbooks so I wanted to know if someone would know how to handle these statements. Especially the statement where "everything is a dog or cat."  Please do not jump to conclusions when you don't know.

Comment: If it is in your study guide it is homework, and also it must be described in a textbook somewhere.

Comment: sadly not ;_; I'm feeling to burn this book lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the first one:

```
dog_or_cat(X) :- dog(X) ; cat(X).
```

This could also be represented with multiple clauses:

```
dog_or_cat(X) :- dog(X).
dog_or_cat(X) :- cat(X).
```

Rule #2 will be similar.

Rule #3. It's common for a statement like this to appear "backwards" in Prolog. This is because Prolog is really attempting to prove something, and to do that it has to fulfill the body of the clause. So let's look at it:

```
dog(X) :- gshephard(X) ; canine(X) ; rottweiler(X).
```

What Prolog will do when it sees `dog(X)` is attempt to find a solution to `gshephard(X)`. If that fails, it will try `canine(X)` etc. That this happens in a certain order is both necessary for computation and a major difference between actual logic and Prolog, but anyway, that's *usually* how implication gets handled in Prolog.

Rules 4 and 5 are similar to 3, except you need to know that negation in Prolog is furnished by the `\+` operator.

**Edit**: In response to your new questions:

```
red_fruit(X) :- fruit(X), red(X).  % question 1
tasty_veg(X) :- vegetable(X), tasty(X). % question 4
```

It looks like you're having trouble with how to say "and" in Prolog. It's just ",", meaning, satisfy this and then that. `red_fruit(X)` is read as "to prove X is a red fruit, first prove X is a fruit, then prove X is red."

Comment: Thanks I will try to implement this and see how it goes. I may comment again if I run int any issues. Thanks.

Comment: @KimberlyJames sounds good! What book are you going through, by the way?

Comment: well the example KB is from my university subject guide and the book I'm going through is Programming in PROLOG: Using the ISO Standard by W.F. Clocksin

Comment: That's actually a great book, but there are actually a lot of good Prolog books if it isn't working for you.

Comment: I encoded another KB into prolog, i'm not sure I did it 100% right, can I post the problem here? or make a new question. I want to query my prolog facts now.

Comment: Edit your question to add that stuff and I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks so much Daniel, I'm very new to stack, please forgive me and also i updated question for the new task :)

Comment: @KimberlyJames I have edited your question and answered it, please take a look

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help! By the way, did I ask the appropriate queries for 2 and 3?